# Michael Hartle Chapter 5: "No route matches" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am using Rails 4.0.8. When I ran `bundle exec rspec spec/`, here's the error I got from the tutorial (http://www.railstutorial.org/book/filling_in_the_layout):

> Pending:   StaticPagesHelper add some examples to (or delete)
>   /Users/Desktop/sample_app/spec/helpers/static_pages_helper_spec.rb
>       # No reason given
>       # ./spec/helpers/static_pages_helper_spec.rb:14
>
> Failures:
>
> 1) StaticPagesController GET '...' returns http success
>        Failure/Error: get '...'
>        ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
>          No route matches {:action=>"...", :controller=>"static_pages"}
>        # ./spec/controllers/static_pages_controller_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in '
>
> Finished in 0.20849 seconds 19 examples, 1 failure, 1 pending
>
> Failed examples:
>
> rspec ./spec/controllers/static_pages_controller_spec.rb:6 #
>   StaticPagesController GET '...' returns http success

Here is my `route.rb` file:

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
resources :users
  root to: 'static_pages#home'
  match '/signup',  to: 'users#new',            via: 'get'
  match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help',    via: 'get'
  match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about',   via: 'get'
  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact', via: 'get'
end
```

Here is my `static_pages_helper_spec.rb` file:

```
require 'spec_helper'

# Specs in this file have access to a helper object that includes
# the StaticPagesHelper. For example:
#
# describe StaticPagesHelper do
#   describe "string concat" do
#     it "concats two strings with spaces" do
#       helper.concat_strings("this","that").should == "this that"
#     end
#   end
# end describe StaticPagesHelper do   pending "add some examples to (or delete) #{__FILE__}" end
```

Here is my `static_pages_controller_spec.rb` file:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe StaticPagesController do

  describe "GET '...'" do
    it "returns http success" do
      get '...'
      response.should be_success
    end
  end

end
```

**app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb**

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end

  def help
  end

  def about
  end

  def contact
  end
end
```

I wonder whether I'm getting the error because my version is not compatible with his tutorial. Should I be looking at this tutorial instead http://rails-3-2.railstutorial.org/book/filling_in_the_layout#sec-rails_routes?

Comment: it says your error is in the `static_pages_controller_spec.rb` line 7.  Can you include that file in your question? The entire `static_pages_controller_spec.rb` in fact.

Comment: I've added the entire static_pages_controller_spec.rb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `static_pages_controller_spec` has

```
  describe "GET '...'" do
    it "returns http success" do
      get '...'
      response.should be_success
    end
  end
```

The `"..."` is nonsense in this context and the tutorial probably included it as a "specimen" entry.

Comment out the above lines, or replace "..." with a real method in your static_pages_controller.rb.  You probably have an `index` method so you could do...

```
  describe "GET index" do
    it "returns http success" do
      get :index
      response.should be_success
    end
  end
```

Cheers

Comment: I did this, and I still get this error:  StaticPagesController GET index returns http success
     Failure/Error: get :index
     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"static_pages"}
     # ./spec/controllers/static_pages_controller_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Comment: Ok, right, so you don't have an 'index' action in your static_pages_controller... I just reviewed your routes.rb and I can see that.   Try this `get '/about'`
That should work.

Comment: I typed get" '/about' " on route.rb and it gave me a huge error that says, "missing: action key on routes..."

Comment: Ok do you have ANYTHING in your static pages controller?

Comment: I just realised you said "I typed "get '/about'" on route.rb...

I meant you should do `get '/about'` in your `static_pages_controller_spec.rb`.   When I mentioned your routes.rb I was talking about what it showed us, not what needs to change in it.

So in summary, IN YOUR `static_pages_controller_spec.rb` REPLACE THE LINE `get '...'` WITH `get '/about'`  :)

Comment: I just tried that, and I'm getting this error: "Failure/Error: get '/about'
     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"/about", :controller=>"static_pages"}"

Comment: Where did you find the original `static_pages_controller_spec.rb` ?  I've now been through the tutorial and I can't see where you got it. Here's how others have done the tutorial on this file... http://code.ohloh.net/file?fid=wIFLi6B2j0kvVnzh22FvHRgkSAc&cid=HpNE9eEc3SM&s=&fp=402978&mp&projSelected=true#L0

Comment: It's in 'spec/controllers/static_pages_controller_spec.rb'. The tutorial on the link you sent worked! Thank you very much.